# HTML - Table with Image and text

Tags: html, image, html-table

I'm having a web page which has a table with only 2 rows and one column. First row will show an image which is dynamic and in the second row, caption related to image will be shown.

I want to show the image as it is without distortion and so I'm not specifying andy height and width for that.

Now if the caption text length is more, the row width will be more than image row width. What I want is that, I want to show the caption in multiline without increasing the row width. So that image and its caption rows are same in width.

Is there any solution for this.... I'm new to HTML and not able to find the solution for this problem.

Comment: Dude, it's 2012 (nearly 2013) - why are you using `<table>` for your layout?

Comment: "'m new to HTML" — Please learn 2012 coding practices and not 1997 coding practises.

Comment: Can you refer me to some good coding practice websites... I'll definitely learn them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td> ...image goes here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td style="width:1px">
    Caption!      
  </td></tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really not how I would do things, but er...

If you know how large you want your rows to be, try adding styling to your table rows, like...

```
<tr style="height:300px" ...
```

That way they will both stay equal height. But if you want it dynamic, then the only way I can think is to use JavaScript to figure the height of the image, and then adjust the table row styling as appropriate. Using jQuery, you could do something like...

```
var img_height = $('table img').height();
$('table tr').height(img_height);
```

(That is providing there is only one table, with one img inside it. You may need to adjust this code as appropriate, it is just an example!)

**Edit:** if the caption could be larger than the image...

Firstly, give the caption row a class of `caption` and give your image row a class of `image`, then use the following jQuery code:

```
var img_height = $('.image').height();
var caption_height = $('.caption:first').height();

if (img_height > caption_height) {
    $('.caption').height(img_height);
} else {
    $('.image').height(caption_height);
}
```

Perhaps read the following for an explanation for how to use the jQuery code: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: I dont know how large will be the image or caption. both are dynamic. where should I write this script?

Comment: Edited my answer. Really, you shouldn't be doing this, though. You should be using `div` elements to position layout elements, not tables.

Comment: Can you please suggest me some code using div so that I can replace tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use this give the table a fixed with in pixel or the width of the dynamic image. this will help. not caption should not be word without spaces, like this mmmmmmmm. It would automatically become multiline

```
<table>
  <tr><td> ...image goes here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td style="width:1px">
    Caption!      
  </td></tr>
 </table>
```